# Why can't I generate app engine client libraries?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to Generate the Client Libraries for my project, from the menu `Tools --> Google Cloud Tools --> Generate Client Libraries`.

It gives me the error `Could not find associated Android library module (nameOfTheProject-endpoints), skipping copying of client libraries into android`. When I hit OK, it keeps doing something but not the whole operation, so my android project won't compile.

I understand the reason of the error.
This is the directories structure of my project

```
nameOfTheProject
|--nameOfTheMainModule
|--nameOfTheMainModule-AppEngine
|--nameOfTheMainModule-endpoints
```

The endpoints folder is there but it's not named `nameOfTheProject-endpoints`, as you can see.

I tried to rename the module and it initially seems to work. After some time though, the name of the module automatically returns the first one and the project gets all messed up (it happened two times and I had to recreate and rebuild the whole project from scratch)

Can I manipulate the name of the endpoints module before its creation?
Can I tell Android Studio to search for the endpoints module somewhere else?
If I can't to any of these two, how do I resolve?

Finally, if there is no help for that, is there a Google Cloud Platform plugin for IntelliJ Idea, that automagically generate endpoints and client library for me?

I love Android Studio, keep up the good work! I'm sure that, once it get finalized, it will be THE Android IDE.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you renaming your module? If you're using the Refactor > Rename command, it brings up a dialog asking if you want to rename the directory or the module: [image: Rename directory or module dialog]

Make sure you choose **Rename directory**. **Rename module** is broken and the name change will only be partial and temporary. This is documented in bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57692.

If you change it in this way, it should rename the directory on disk and also update your `settings.gradle` file, and the changes should be permanent. I'm not sure if that will actaully solve your Cloud Endpoints issues or not though.

Comment: thank you for the detailed question, it really helped.
I wanted to make sure of a thing though, could this be just my maven installation not being compatible with android studio maybe? I ask because from 6 months the feature was implemented this is the first question of the kind on the web...

Comment: I'm not really sure. I haven't worked with Cloud Endpoints much at all.